# Complete list of material color theming attributes

Tags: android, android-xml, material-design

I'm looking to apply Material Design into my app. I've read about [using material themes](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) and about how I can [customise these with my own colours](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette) from the Android Developer website, however the webpage only describes a few of the material design attributes I can use in my `themes.xml`.

The webpage only refers to the main theming attributes:
- `colorPrimary`: The app's main branding colour
- `colorPrimaryDark`: A darker variant used for status bars and contextual app bars
- `colorAccent`: The accent colour, to theme some UI controls

It also describes some other attributes shown in the diagram below:

[image]

However, I want to know ***all of the different theming attributes that can be applied*** to a material design theme. For example, I know there are other attributes such as `colorButtonNormal`, but I want to know the full list of these attributes ***and what they each do***.

Comment: more details in  [material theming guide page](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that there's a detailed description of each attribute. You can dive into the sources and try to guess the purpose of each attribute. See: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes_material.xml

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Zielony's answer, you can find descriptions here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html